# AudioKit cannot record microphone

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, audiokit

I'm using the latest version of AudioKit, 4.8. I have set up a simple audio chain to record some audio from the microphone, and it works great on the simulator, but when I switch to a physical device, nothing is recorded and it keeps printing this is the console:

```
AKNodeRecorder.swift:process(buffer:time:):137:Write failed: error -> Cannot complete process.（“com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio”Error -50.）
```

So you see, nothing is recorded. -50 is the bad param error, but obviously I couldn't find what I'm missing. The audio session is set to `playAndRecord` and I DID request the microphone usage. If I don't use `AKNodeRecorder` but add my own tap instead, the same error still shows up when I try `AKAudioFile.write(from:)`.

Here's my code:

```
    guard let file = try? AKAudioFile(forWriting: destinationURL, settings: [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC, AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue]) else {
        return
    }

    microphone?.start()

    let recorder = try? AKNodeRecorder(node: microphone, file: file)
    try? recorder?.record()
```

What should I do?

P.S. before I upgraded to AudioKit 4.8, I was using 4.7, and instead of giving me error -50, it simply crashed when I began recording on a physical device, giving me this. All is fine on simulators.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: '[[busArray objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)element] setFormat:format error:&nsErr]: returned false, error Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10865 "(null)"'
```